# How do I run an already existing asp.net mvc application om my local server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am front-end developer trying to brush up the front-end of an existing asp.net mvc application. So I have never used asp before but I thought I would try running it locally on my machine then get to work on the css part of the web application.

Previously I have tried running IIS server locally but in vain, is there a better way to run this project? Sorry I am not allowed to share the repo from where I have cloned the project.

I am using Visual Studio code running on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Visual Studio. It has its own IIS Express so you can run app locally and open it in any browser and you can also edit all HTML and CSS files.

Comment: What about the DB migrations?

Comment: Is there any test database already deployed anywhere? If there is, you can simply connect your application to test database and continue your work.

Comment: Alright, thanks.How do you connect it to a test database?

Comment: I don't know how your database communication is implemented, but usually there is a <connectionStrings> area in Web.config file in your project. You can redirect the connection string to connect to your test database.

Comment: Thanks Matt, can't help but ask about everything as its my first asp application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS, go to  Under Default Web site.
2. right click and add select *Add Application*
3. give alias name and select the physical path of your source code
4. click Ok

   if you get database access Authorization failed.
5. Open SQL Express Management Studio as an “Administrator” and navigate to Security > Logins > NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
6. Right click on “NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM” and select Properties. Select “Server Roles” from the left panel and make sure that “public” and “sysadmin” are checked.

Your application will be added under Default Web Site
from there you can browse.

You can have a look at very  good article,
[how to deploy ASP.NET MVC application on IIS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploying-your-Asp-Net-mvc-5-app-to-iis-8/)

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to use latest Visual Studio and import your project into it (File->Open-Project/Solution) and run the application in it in debug mode. You can put break point to go through the code and add new codes and even test your application. It is very easy indeed. It has all the utilities for a .NET MVC application.